# How to customize the variables in vuetify in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify in Laravel. I had created a laravel 8 project with vue version 2 using laravel/ui package. Everything seems to work fine and all the components of vuetify rendered properly. But when I try to change a variable in my `variables.scss` in `resources/sass/variables.scss`, It doesn't seems to work accordingly. e.g: when i want to change the default border radius from 4px to let say 10px using `$border-radius-root: 6px;` as mentioned in vuetify documentation. It doesn't work. Below is my `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

require("vuetifyjs-mix-extension");

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .vuetify()
    .vue({ version: 2 })
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css");
```

And my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.24",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.39",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.43.4",
        "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "vuetifyjs-mix-extension": "^0.0.20"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@mdi/font": "^6.4.95",
        "@mdi/js": "^6.4.95",
        "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
        "vuetify": "^2.5.14",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.3",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
    }
}
```

my app.scss file content

```
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito");

// Variables
@import url("variables.scss");
```

my variables.scss content

```
$border-radius-root: 14px !important;  // this portion didn't work.
```

and the vuetify.js plugin file content

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
// To add vuetify css file
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";
import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css"; // Ensure you are using css-loader
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"; // Ensure you are using css-loader

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const opts = {
    icons: {
        iconfont: "mdi" || "mdiSvg" || "md",
    },
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: "#26695C", // #E53935
                secondary: colors.indigo.accent4, // #FFCDD2
                accent: "#BA895D", // #3F51B5
                black: "#000000",
                primaryLight: "#E9F0EE",
            },
        },
    },
};
// primary: "#DB6015", // #E53935
// secondary: colors.indigo.accent4, // #FFCDD2
// accent: "#005677" // #3F51B5
export default new Vuetify(opts);
```

and I am using the [vuetifyjs-mix-extension](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/vuetifyjs) in my laravel mix configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult with the approach you are trying to use for. I can suggest the following one:
vuetify.js (imported in the app)

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";
import es from "vuetify/lib/locale/es";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
    // More props here...
  },
  // More stuffs here...
});
```

webpack.mix.js

```js
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
require("vuetifyjs-mix-extension");

mix
  .js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .vue()
  // here's where the magic happens.
  .vuetify("vuetify-loader", { extract: "[name].csss" })
  .version()
  .disableNotifications();
```

Now that you have these settings. Ensure you...

1. Have the following file: `resources/sass/variables.scss`
2. If you have custom fonts, it's preferable that you import them via html rather than here, that's more efficient.

You will be able to see the updates on your code.

**Side note:** There are my plugins versions:

```js
{
  //...
  "dependencies": {
    //...,
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...,
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.24",
    "postcss": "^8.2.12",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.3.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.2",
    "vuetifyjs-mix-extension": "^0.0.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: okay, let me try that.